# Can't make sqlite3 work on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, sqlite

I just installed ruby on my windows 7 computer. I installed rails and sqlite3 with the gem. I then made my app work on local BUT I still seem to have problems with sqlite3. When I try this:

```
rake db:create
```

the only thing i get is an error:

```
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: "gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter" (sqlite3 
is not part of the bundle. Add it to the GemFile).
```

I've been doing some digging here and there, and I could make this error go away adding this line to my GemFile:

```
gem "sqlite3", group: :sqlite3
```

And i got a new error:

```
no driver for sqlite3 found
```

I tried the 'bundle' command and I have both sqlite3 and sqlite3-ruby, I reinstalled everything but the problem won't go away. This is my gemFile, I hope it helps:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#I tried this too, but nothig changes
#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem "sqlite3", group: :sqlite3


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I really don't know what to do. It's kind of frustrating, it seems like something is not (obviously) properly working with sqlite3, because fixing one error leads to a new error. How can I possibly fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried just `gem 'sqlite3'`? And I assume you've run `bundle install`...?

Comment: Yeah, if I keep the "gem 'sqlite3' " it says that it cannot load sqlite3/sqlite3_native files, that's why I changed it, and yes I ran the bundle install

...
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.17.0)
Using railties (3.2.12)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
Using rails (3.2.12)
Using sass (3.2.7)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7)
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
Using uglifier (1.3.0)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.

Here it is!

Comment: Is sqlite3 installed in your system?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the .dll and .exe files, the ran the gem install sqlite3, and as you can see from the bundle, it's there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everybody who's going to have this problem. What I did to fix it was uninstall everything. I though that maybe since I had an updated version of everything, something might not be working properly, maybe some dependencies were wrongly addressed. So I reinstalled everything following this:

[Rails Installer Website](http://railsinstaller.org/)

Which will make you install everything you need to run your first RoR app. It might not be up to date but it works just fine. Sqlite3 works perfectly now and that was what I needed. I might try to update every single program later, right now I just need something that is actually working. Thanks to everybody else who tried to help.